# Do I start by using the law of inclusion exclusion?

Tags: probability

[image]

Do I start by using the law of inclusion exclusion?

Comment: Please don't re-post closed questions. Instead, edit closed questions so that they're suitable to be reopened. More information about how this site works can be found in the [help]

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: Please read the instructions on the duplicate question about how self-study questions work.